# Does any algorithm loops at some point?

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, finite-automata, loops

Given that any implementable algorithm has a finite number of internal states, and given that any state is determined by the previous one, does that implies that any algorithm loops at some point?
If I run the algorithm until the number of state transitions is greater than the number of internal states, by the [pigeonhole principle,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) I should eventually get into a loop. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are technically correct. A modern practical computer has finitely many states, and so any program it runs will eventually repeat a state.

However, I would like to warn against interpreting this observation in the wrong way. It is *not* a problem in practice. The number of possible states is huge (it's huuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuge). Algorithms that are designed for machines with infinite resources (such as Turing machines) typically run just fine on a modern computer. Of course, they may use up all available memory if they are especially memory-intensive, but that's different from them cycling because they somehow repeated a configuration due to computer limitations. And when programs do cycle forever unintentionally, it is not the limited size of the computer that does it, but rather programming errors.

It is *more practical* to mathematically model modern computers as if they have unlimited memory than to model them as finite-state machines. This situation is a bit like modelling in physics: classical fluid dynamics models a discrete system of atoms as if it were a continuous one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following algorithm:

- $n \gets 0$
- repeat: $n \gets n+1$

The algorithm runs for infinitely many steps without repeating the same state.

Comment: I mean implementable algorithm on a real machine. On  a real machine, memory is finite, hence the number of possible internal states is finite. The assumption here is a finite number of internal states (e.g. Turing machine with a finite number of symbols and tape

Comment: By an *algorithm* we usually mean a theoretical construct which is not limited in any way. If you limit your algorithm artificially to have finitely many possible states, then what you wrote is correct.

Comment: @Gianluca Ghettini: Provided that by "finite" you mean "of a bounded and input-independent size" (which is the case for real-life computers), then Turing machines with finite amount of symbols and tape are computationally equivalent to (deterministic) finite automata.